# Adicionar valores a uma lista C#

Tags: c#, lista

Olá ! Estou a ler valores de uma tabela e a inserir numa lista. O que eu tenho é isto:

```
Expiração.Add(rdr["Name" + "Address"].ToString());
Expiração.Add(rdr["Address"].ToString());
Expiração.Add(rdr["PostalCode"].ToString());
Expiração.Add(rdr["PostalCodeDesc"].ToString());
Expiração.Add(rdr["NIF"].ToString());
Expiração.Add(rdr["eMail"].ToString());
Expiração.Add(rdr["Phone"].ToString());
Expiração.Add(rdr["ContactPerson"].ToString());
Expiração.Add(rdr["Machine"].ToString());
Expiração.Add(rdr["RegistrationDate"].ToString());
```

Mas assim estou a adicionar vários itens à lista, o que eu queria era adicionar só um item com aquela informação toda, algo assim (só exemplo, porque assim nao funciona):

```
Expiração.Add(rdr["Name" + "Address" + "PostalCode" + ...].ToString());
```

Comment: O que tens de fazer é criar uma classe que seja composta pelas colunas da tabela. A partir dai crias uma Lista dessa classe: ex: List<NomeDaClasse>.  Se tiveres dúvida sobre o código a fazer, diz. Ps: pesquisa por EntityFramework

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia ter um objeto: Expiracao, que teria todas as propriedades que voce precisa. Algo como:

```
public class Expiracao(){
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
    public string PostalCode {get; set;}
    public string PostalCodeDesc {get; set;}
    public string NIF {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string Phone {get; set;}
    public string ContactPerson {get; set;}
    public string Machine {get; set;}
    public string RegistrationDate {get; set;}
}
```

E, imaginando que seu rdr seja um obj que implemente: `IDataReader`, seria algo como:

```
var objExpiracao = new Expiracao();
objExpiracao.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
objExpiracao.Address = rdr["Address"].ToString();
objExpiracao.PostalCode = rdr["PostalCode"].ToString();
...
```

Ou, ao invés de buscar por nome, poderia buscar por índice, algo como: `rdr[0]`, de acordo com a seleção da sua instrução - `SELECT Name, Addres FROM TB_Expiracao`

E assim para todas as propriedades do objeto que quiser popular. 
Ainda poderá adicionar este objeto a uma lista de objetos: Expiracao:

```
var lExpiracao = new List<Expiracao>();
lExpiracao.Add(objExpiracao);
```

Para acessar os dados do seu objeto, utilizará: objeto.propriedade:

```
console.WriteLine(objExpiracao.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é criar um método de leitura para te auxiliar destes dados da tabela uma forma de se fazer isso é utilizando o `params` para assim passar as colunas separadas por `,`:

```
   private List<string> LerDados(DbDataReader reader,params string[] colunas)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var col in colunas)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader[col].ToString()))
                list.Add(reader[col].ToString());
        }
        return list;

    }
```

Ou então você pode utilizar o conceito da classe estendida

```
public static class Extend
{
    public static List<string> ToList(this DbDataReader reader, params string[] colunas)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var col in colunas)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader[col].ToString()))
                list.Add(reader[col].ToString());
        }
        return list;

    }
}
```

Para utilizar:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    List<string> Expiração = reader.ToList("Name", "Address", "PostalCode");
}
```

Comment: O usuário que negativou poderia explicar o motivo ou apontar onde está o erro, para que eu possa fazer as correções necessárias ou se for o caso  remover a minha resposta.

Comment: Ultimamente está acontecendo isso... a galera vem e negativa mas não fala nada... complicado viu.

Comment: É então, eu não sei se a minha resposta está errada, me parece que responde o que o DC perguntou, mas eu posso errar e minha resposta estar completamente errada, mas eu preciso saber para fazer a ação correta.